# Split contents of a directory into multiple sub directories

Tags: command-line, directory

I have a directory which contain more than thousand images. I want to split the files in to multiple sub directories, each containing 100 files. How do I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63265/distributing-thousands-of-files-over-subfolders (this isn't Ubuntu-specific).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

the following worked well for me. Open the directory in terminal, and just copy & paste the following script, press enter. sub directories will be created inside having names dir_001, dir_002 and so on.

```
i=0; 
for f in *; 
do 
    d=dir_$(printf %03d $((i/100+1))); 
    mkdir -p $d; 
    mv "$f" $d; 
    let i++; 
done
```

Comment: This was flagged as low quality. Since you are the OP, could you add an explanation of what you have done?

Comment: done. Have added an explanation.

Comment: works as expected!!

Answer (score 1):

Move fixed number of files using array with range and offset.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

a=(./src/*)
for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i+=100)); do
    printf -v b ./img_%03d $((++n))
    mkdir -p $b && mv -t $b "${a[@]:$i:100}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This will prompt you with how many directories you want and the sub-directory prefix.
The ls command is just a reminder of how many files you've got.

```
ls -1 | wc -l

read -p 'How Many Directories: ' F;
read -p 'Sub-Directories Prefix: ' S;

PARRENT=${PWD}
# cd $PARRENT 
n=0
for i in *
do
  if [ $((n+=1)) -gt $F ]; then
    n=1
  fi
  todir=$PARRENT/"$S"_$n
  [ -d "$todir" ] || mkdir "$todir" 
  mv "$i" "$todir" 
done
```

Source: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/248539-split-folder-huge-number-files-n-folders.html

Comment: I'm afraid this will cause problems if current directory have spaces in path, but I might be wrong.